# setString in JDBC select

Tags: java, sql, string, select, jdbc

I´m trying to setString for Statement in JDBC. But I dont know how can I setString for this example:

```
public static final String SELECT_ST = "SELECT name, car FROM rating WHERE car= ?";

try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_URL, JDBC_USER, JDBC_PASSWD);
         PreparedStatement statement1 = connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_ST);
         Statement statement2 = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
    ) {
        try(ResultSet rs = statement2.executeQuery(SELECT_ST)){

            //some code here
            
        }
    }catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new ScoreException("Some problem here", e);
    }
```

How can I setString for ? in SELECT_ST?

Comment: Rather than posting, you could have searched Stack Overflow to find many pieces of example code in existing Answers.

Comment: The [official JDBC prepared statement tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) also walks through how do do this.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is PreparedStatement#setString.

Your code should be something like:

```java
try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_URL, JDBC_USER, JDBC_PASSWD);
         PreparedStatement statement1 = connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_ST);
         PreparedStatement  statement2 = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
    ) {
        statement2.setString(1, "BMW"); //Set your where condition
        try(ResultSet rs = statement2.executeQuery(SELECT_ST)){

            //some code here
            
        }
    }catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new ScoreException("Some problem here", e);
    }
```

Not sure why you have statement1 though :)